# OpenThread Border Router on Android Thing device

Tags: android-things, openthread

I am starting to develop for Android Things and I was wondering if it was possible to implement OpenThread Border Router  on a Raspberry PI 3B with Android Things flashed into it.

https://github.com/openthread/openthread
https://github.com/openthread/borderrouter

"A Border Router connects a Thread network to networks at different layers, such as WiFi or Ethernet. OpenThread Border Router provides end-to-end IP via routing between Thread devices and other external IP networks, as well as external Thread Commissioning."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: While Border Routing functionality isn't available on Android Things, the Android team released a new API that adds first-class support for Thread radios. This makes it possible to develop Android applications that implement border routing functionality equivalent to `borderrouter`. See the [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/lowpan-on-android-things.html) for more details. Note that I'm not aware of any implementations at this time as I no longer work on the project.

---------- Original reply ----------

I work on the OpenThread team. Currently, the borderrouter project targets Linux platforms and has been demonstrated on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jesse Lite. Android Things is not supported at this time. We plan on supporting more platforms but I have no updates of when new ones will be added. Please file a feature request [issue](https://github.com/openthread/borderrouter/issues/new) on Github.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for this amazing work you are doing